# How to use JavaScript to set style top property by using timer in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript.I'm try to write a float layer. The following code is work on non HTML5

```
<html>
<body  onLoad="initSession()">

<div id="demo"></div>

<div id="flotLayer" style="position:absolute;width:60px;height:60px;z-index:30;visibility:hidden;right: 10px;top:0px;">
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid 1px #cccccc">floatLayer</div>
</div>
<div style="width:100px; height:5000px;"></div>

<script>
setInterval(() => {
  myTimer() 
}, 50);

setInterval(MoveLayer, 50);
function myTimer() {
  const d = document.getElementById('flotLayer').style.top;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
function initSession() {
    document.getElementById('flotLayer').style.visibility = 'visible';
    MoveLayer(); 
    myTimer();
    
}
function MoveLayer() {
    
    var x = 50;
    var y = 250; 
    var _y = document.body.scrollTop + y;
    var diff =(_y - parseInt(document.getElementById('flotLayer').style.top))*.50;
    var rey=_y-diff;

    document.getElementById('flotLayer').style.top=rey.toString() + "px";
    document.getElementById('flotLayer').style.right=x.toString() + "px";
    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I declare HTML5 Doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`
The timer look like only run one time.Can anyone give me some hints?

The symptom to look for when replicating this is that scrolling the page down, with the doctype the `floatLayer` scrolls off the top of the page. Without a doctype, it moves up but then is moved back down to be centered vertically.

Comment: yes it will run only one time because the timer starts at same time for both.

Comment: double your second timer time or you have to use promises/Asyc

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your response. When I have <!doctype html> at the top and scroll the page. The float layer will fix on the same position. I'm using w3c online editor to testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some debugging shows that with the doctype, `document.body.scrollTop` is always `0`, but without it, it grows as the page is scrolled upward.

Different rendering engines had different approaches to whether the main page scroll is scrolling the `body` element or the `html` element. Apparently changing the doctype changes Chromium-based browsers from scrolling `body` to scrolling `html`.

To make it work regardless of which one is scrolled, use the one that's non-zero:

```
var _y = (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop) + y;
```

Comment: Thank You for your help! I've learned so much.